# What's the difference between 1kb(64x16) and 1kb(128x8) for EEPROM memory size?

Tags: integrated-circuit, memory, eeprom

In addition to the question in the title, I have the following subquestions:

1. I'm guessing 64x16 means something like 64 cells of 16 bytes each. Is this accurate?
2. What is the significance (if any) of the memory being 64x16 vs 128x8?
3. What is the specific term (if any) for this (i.e. 1kb being composed of 64x16)?

The questions are made with reference to this:
[EEPROM IC memory size comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSTMD.jpg)
From https://www.digikey.sg/short/pb7488

Comment: Study the data sheets of the two parts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

64x16 means that the memory is arranged as 64 words of 16 bits each.  128x8 means that the memory is arranged as 128 words of 8 bits each (i.e., 128 bytes).  You read, erase, and write on a word-by-word basis.

In general, wider words are faster, but because you must erase an entire word at a time, they're less convenient.

Those are some pretty old memory chips you're looking at!